# Why can't I install any packages using apt-get?

Tags: 12.04, apt

I can't install any packages using `apt-get`. For example this is the error I get while trying to install `macchanger` or anything for that matter:

```
cody@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install macchanger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package google-chrome-stable:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
cody@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

It's very strange and it would be a big help if someone could tell me how to fix this problem.

By the way, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I believe it's 32-bit

Edit: I cant open my Ubuntu package manager either. It opens for about two seconds then closes.

Answer (score 2):

`google-chrome-stable` must be broken. First, run `apt-get update` to ensure APT's package lists are up to date (to avoid dependency issues), then download a new copy of [Google Chrome](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) and install it by running:

```
cd Downloads  # <- The directory where the file was downloaded to
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Comment: I would strongly advise using a PPA with Google Chrome, instead of installing the package.

Comment: @meskobalazs Google Chrome is a proprietary software (as opposed to Chromium), so it can't be included in a PPA (Personal Package Archive). Nevertheless, as stated at Chrome's [download page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/#eula), "Installing Google Chrome will **add the Google repository** so your system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date", so I can't see any problem with this installing method.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about the updates, then it's okay (upvoted the answer).